# How to write a custom component that uses the ID of its parent when rendering some javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, jsf-2.2, omnifaces

I would like to write a custom component that renders a javascript function. It would basically behave as the omnifaces onloadscript, and it would use the client ID of its enclosing parent as a parameter to the javascript function.

Example:

```
<h:panelGroup id="panel">
    <my:component />
</h:panelGroup>
```

I've started to write such a custom component, using the implementation of the omnifaces onloadscript as a guideline. Looks good so far, but when the enclosing parent is a composite component, the actual parent of my custom component is not the composite component but the parent of the insertChildren tag.

While this makes sense, this is of course not the behavior I want.

Example:

```
<my:composite id="panel">
    <my:component />
</my:composite>
```

The client ID of the parent of my:component is not 'panel' if the composite uses an insertChildren tag in its implementation.

Questions:

- How can I fix this problem?
- Could my custom component be a tag handler that would create a single resource component in the view root, instead of an actual UI component moved to the view root?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution.

I've implemented a tag handler that adds a UI component to the view tree when the tag is processed. See comments in the code below. The tag handler:

```
private final TagAttribute someAttribute;

@Override
public void apply(FaceletContext ctx, UIComponent parent) {
    UIComponent parentOfParent = parent != null ? parent.getParent() : null;

    // process only when created
    if (parent != null && parentOfParent == null) {
        Supplier<String> scriptProvider = getScriptProvider(ctx, parent);
        ScriptComponent scriptComponent = new ScriptComponent(scriptProvider);
        parent.getChildren().add(scriptComponent);
        // note: the actual script is obtained when the ScriptComponent is rendered
    }
}

protected Supplier<String> getScriptProvider(FaceletContext ctx, UIComponent target) {
    // this is invoked when the tag is processed, so it's Ok for the EL context
    String someValue = someAttribute.getValue(ctx);

    return () -> {
        // this is invoked by the script component when it is rendered,
        // so we have the correct client ID even if the target is a composite component
        String targetId = target.getClientId();
        return String.format("myFunction('%s', '%s');", targetId, someValue);
    };
}
```

The UI component:

```
private final Supplier<String> scriptProvider;

@Override
public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
    writer.append("\n");
    writer.startElement("script", this);
    writer.append("\n");

    String script = scriptProvider.get();
    writer.append(script);
    writer.append("\n");
}

@Override
public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
    writer.endElement("script");
}
```